# Print Sample for MonoMac

Tags: printing, monomac

Does anyone know of a MonoMac sample that shows how to implement Print (to a printer)? I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, but the conceptual docs from Apple are relevant, and their sample snippets should be straightforward to port to C#: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Printing.html

Comment: Yes, I've read through quite a few different Cocoa printing docs and have a few Objective-C OS X books that cover printing as well.  There are things missing from the current MonoMac that prevent a NSView from printing.

Comment: See NSView reference for the Printing & Pagination methods. Where do you file bugs for MonoMac?

Answer (score 0):

I created a PrintDocument class a bit like this: 
(You'd need to set a proper size and add some drawing in drawrect)

```
public class PrintDocument:NSView   {

    NSPrintOperation MyPrinter = null;
    static IntPtr selCurrentContext = Selector.GetHandle ("currentContext");
    static IntPtr classNSGraphicsContext = Class.GetHandle ("NSGraphicsContext");

    public PrintDocument ()
    {
        MyPrinter=NSPrintOperation.FromView(this);
        this.SetFrameSize(new SizeF(600,800));
    }

    public void Print ()
    {
        MyPrinter.RunOperation()
    }
    public override void DrawRect (RectangleF dirtyRect)
    {
        var context = new NSGraphicsContext (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (classNSGraphicsContext, selCurrentContext));
        //NSPrintOperation.CurrentOperation
    }

}
```